# Why does Case written this way bring a 'ghost' row in my table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Question: Write a query that calculates the combined weight of all underclass players (FR/SO) in California as well as the combined weight of all upperclass players (JR/SR) in California.

My Answer:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN state = 'CA' AND year IN ('FR', 'SO')
    THEN 'underclass'
    WHEN state = 'CA' AND year IN ('JR', 'SR')
    THEN 'upperclass'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS class_divide,
  SUM(weight) AS combined_weights
FROM benn.college_football_players
GROUP BY 1
```

[Results](https://app.mode.com/dswaine/reports/f716e6389dbd/details/queries/1a3ad9a7675e/data):

```
| class_divide | combined_weights |
+--------------+------------------+
|              | 5326369.0        |
| upperclass   | 262452.0         |
| underclass   | 274374.0         |
```

Correct Answer:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN year IN ('FR', 'SO')
    THEN 'underclass'
    WHEN year IN ('JR', 'SR')
    THEN 'upperclass'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS class_group,
  SUM(weight) AS combined_player_weight
FROM benn.college_football_players
WHERE state = 'CA'
GROUP BY 1
```

Why does it work to add

```
Where state = 'CA'
```

after the CASE and not within the CASE? Thanks in advance.

Bonus question: Is naming columns using numbers i.e Group by 1 a feature unique to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CASE` expression does not filter out any rows.  So the non-CA rows are all grouped into the `NULL` group.

Note that `ELSE NULL` is redundant, because that is the default if nothing matches.

As for `GROUP BY 1` . . . This is definitely *not* standard syntax but most modern databases seems to support it.  Of course, most modern databases also use Postgres as their code base, because the Postgres license allows its code base to be incorporated into paying products.

Comment: "*Of course, most modern databases also use Postgres as their code base*" - YMMD :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     CASE
     WHEN year IN ('FR', 'SO') THEN 'Underclass'
     WHEN year IN ('JR', 'SR') THEN 'upperclass'
     ELSE NULL END AS class_group,
SUM(weight) AS combined_player_weight
FROM benn.college_football_players
WHERE state = 'CA'
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The larger answer to your question is that the `CASE ... END` block is a separate clause that applies only to the first column of your result set. Though Postgres will parse it just fine without parentheses, it often helps to wrap that block in parentheses to give yourself a visual cue of how far those conditions extend. At the *end* of that block, you are back at the level of your query. Your query only has `SELECT... FROM...GROUP BY`, meaning that your result set will include all records in the selected fields, grouped as you've specified. In this outer level (the main query), you will still need a `WHERE` clause if you want to limit your `SELECT`.